# How to match tops and bottoms of vertical profiles of varying length while interpolating the middle

Tags: r, match, interpolation

I am working with a dataset in R where we have profiles based on section bins. For example, imagine a soil core that is sectioned into 20-cm sections with measurements for each of those sections. That core might not be a factor of 20, so we sectioned from the top, and bottom of the cores, so that differences in length would be in the interior of the core where we have little interest.

Multiple cores were collected for different analyses so the lengths do not perfectly match. Sometimes, one of the cores might even have an extra section or two.

This project is focused on interfaces, so what I would like to do is match the top and bottom halves of cores from a particular sampling event. Then whatever remains in the interior can be interpolated linearly between any leftover data to produce single values for the section bins at their middle point.

Here is an example of before data:

```r
structure(
  list(
    Sample_Day = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1),
    Top = c(102, 82, 62, 42, 20, 110, 90, 70, 50, 40, 20),
    Bottom = c(82, 62, 42, 22, 0, 90, 70, 50, 40, 20, 0),
    Section_Length = c(20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 10, 20, 20),
    Parameter = c("Temp", "Temp", "Temp", "Temp", "Temp", "Chemical", "Chemical", "Chemical", "Chemical", "Chemical", "Chemical"),
    Value = c(10, 6, 4, 2, 1, 1, 2, 3, 2, 1, 1),
    Index = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6)
  ),
  row.names = c(NA, -11L),
  class = "data.frame"
)

#>    Sample_Day Top Bottom Section_Length Parameter Value Index
#> 1           1 102     82             20      Temp    10     1
#> 2           1  82     62             20      Temp     6     2
#> 3           1  62     42             20      Temp     4     3
#> 4           1  42     22             20      Temp     2     4
#> 5           1  20      0             20      Temp     1     5
#> 6           1 110     90             20  Chemical     1     1
#> 7           1  90     70             20  Chemical     2     2
#> 8           1  70     50             20  Chemical     3     3
#> 9           1  50     40             10  Chemical     2     4
#> 10          1  40     20             20  Chemical     1     5
#> 11          1  20      0             20  Chemical     1     6
```

Here is an example of what I would like to generate and iterate through different sampling days. Notice that the `Temp` value (`3`) for `Index == 4` never existed in the original data, and is a simple linear interpolation.

```r
structure(
  list(
    Sample_Day = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1),
    Top = c(110, 90, 70, 50, 40, 20),
    Bottom = c(90, 70, 50, 40, 20, 0),
    Section_Length = c(20, 20, 20, 10, 20, 20),
    Temp = c(10, 6, 4, 3, 2, 1),
    Chemical = c(1, 2, 3, 2, 1, 1),
    Index = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6)
  ),
  row.names = c(NA, -6L),
  class = "data.frame"
)

#>   Sample_Day Top Bottom Section_Length Temp Chemical Index
#> 1          1 110     90             20   10        1     1
#> 2          1  90     70             20    6        2     2
#> 3          1  70     50             20    4        3     3
#> 4          1  50     40             10    3        2     4
#> 5          1  40     20             20    2        1     5
#> 6          1  20      0             20    1        1     6
```

I am currently struggling on how to approach this so any advice on what you might do is extremely welcome. My thoughts are that I could perhaps use the length of a particular parameter to identify which one is shorter, then somehow use the index to match the shorter to the longer core section by bouncing between matching the top then the bottom until it reaches the center where it could add `NA`s and I could get it to linearly interpolate the gaps after.

Comment: Isn't it `Index == 6` that has no `Temp` value, which must be interpolated?

Comment: Thank you very much. This was a hard one to explain. The idea is to take half of the shorter core and match it with the top half of the longer; bottom half of shorter and match it with the bottom of the longer. By doing this, you end up with the gap in the middle. Hope that makes sense!

I see where I went wrong building this example. I should have used unique indices, 1-11, and made two columns of them.

Comment: How does one identify the halves of cores?  Or the cores themselves, for that matter?

Comment: @Greg The core identification is the easy part. In this example, we have two cores that are identified by their 'Parameter', i.e., Chemical and Temp. The splitting of the core is most definitely the hard part. How do you split the core in half? The index column is how I have been thinking to approach this, by using something like a for loop focused on split and cut. 'split(Index,  cut(seq_along(Index), 2, labels = FALSE)'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

one approach, interpolating *all* variables of the shorter subset:

- create helper function which takes a vector *xs*, splits it (at the lower point in case of odd items) and fills the central gap with a simple linear interpolation to reach desired length *n*:

```
fill_gap <- function(xs, n){
  len <- length(xs)
  split_point <- floor(length(xs)/2)
  the_head <- head(xs, split_point)
  the_tail <- tail(xs, len - split_point)
  the_fill <- seq(rev(the_head)[1], the_tail[1], length.out = 2 + n - len)
  c(head(the_head, split_point - 1), the_fill, the_tail[-1])
}
```

```
> fill_gap(1:3, 5)
[1] 1.000000 1.333333 1.666667 2.000000 3.000000
```

- use {dplyr} and {tidyr} convenient grouping and nesting to expand variables of the smaller group (shorter variable length; here: Temp) to the length of the larger group (her: Chemical):

```
d_filled <- 
  d |>  
  pivot_wider(names_from = Parameter, 
              values_from = -Parameter, 
              values_fn = list
              ) |>
  rowwise() |>
  mutate(required_length = max(length(Value_Chemical), length(Value_Temp))) |> 
  ungroup() |> 
  mutate(across(!required_length, ~ list(fill_gap(xs = .x[[1]], n = required_length)))) |>
  unnest_longer(everything())
```

- pick desired variables (or leave as is)

```
d_filled |>
  select(Sample_Day = Sample_Day_Temp,
         starts_with('Top'), ## e. g. depths get interpolated, too
         starts_with('Value'),
         )
```

```
# A tibble: 6 x 5
  Sample_Day Top_Temp Top_Chemical Value_Temp Value_Chemical
       <dbl>    <dbl>        <dbl>      <dbl>          <dbl>
1          1      102          110         10              1
2          1       82           90          6              2
3          1       72           70          5              3
4          1       62           50          4              2
5          1       42           40          2              1
6          1       20           20          1              1
```

Comment: It is going to take me a bit of time work through each of these steps to understand it, but this might be it, without modification! Thank you, and I'll get back to confirming and accepting asap.

Comment: I'm sorry; the initial version was quite straightforward. Then I got caught in trying to generalize it ... I think the two "catches" are a) to accomodate a vector in a single cell (via `values_fn = list`) and, further down, b) remembering to pick a list item (`[[1]]`), not a list, to feed it into the custom `fill_gap`. The rest is the magic of {dplyr} and {tidyr}.

Comment: No need to apologize. This is doing exactly what was asked. These are helpful additional points to be aware of as I start feeding it more complicated data. Thank you!